# How the VC++ compiler report error before the compilation is started by the programmer ?

Tags: visual-c++

As soon as I start writing any undefined variable in my C code in MSVC, I see a red line comes under the statement automatically. This is indeed a very good feature.   But my question is how is this error reported even though the compilation has not been initiated by me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSVC has a special background compiler for that. First it was introduced for Visual Basic, then to C# and now it is available for C/C++.

Comment: Is there a particular instance when this background compiler starts working?

Comment: Yes, it is vcpkgsrv.exe.